# QT building applications for arm linux

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, arm

I got a little confused when it comes to QT and cross compiling
appliations for my arm-linux:

So far I have a linux running on my AT91SAM9263-EK and an appropriate
filessystem including QT libs build via buildroot.

Also I have build QT-4.8 on my ubuntu.

Now I want to build an example application:

1. I created a makefile in an examples folder in QT on my ubuntu using
   qmake; I used the given qmake.conf in mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++.
2. when executing make I get an error because it includes qatomic_i386.h
   and the message "error: impossible constraint in 'asm'".
   this header file does obviously not match to my arm toolchain.

my question:
how to configure Qt on my ubuntu to build Qt binaries for my embedded linux
on arm? Do I need to include any libs build by the arm toolchain?

any help is appreciated!

regards

EDIT:
I use the -spec flag and pass the path to "mkspecs/qws/arm-linux-g++" where a "qmake.conf" is located. I did not change anything in here because I dont know wich qmake variable are relevant to link to my arm related libs.
So the right compiler is used, which I could verify when the make process starts. But I observed that in a config file called qconfig.h there is an ARCH flag which is set to i386 but I didnt figure out how one can configure this. I dont think I should manually edit this file.

EDIT2:
someone knows whats behind the file qconfig.h?? should I adjust it manually?

Comment: the qmake reference manual is a good place to find all qmake.conf variables: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will solve it by myself :)

After struggling a while and scanning the web I got a little deeper involved how everything works together. I did not understand how to generate an executable for my ARM target device. I figured out two things:

1. do not add your QT path for X11 at the beginning in your PATH variable. this might mess up your cross compilation.
2. edit the qmake.conf correspondingly. add your libs build for the target device which in my case are located within buildroot. Add theses lines to your qmake.conf file:
   QMAKE_CFLAGS           += -O3 -march=armv5te
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         += -O3 -march=armv5te
   QMAKE_INCDIR_QT     = /home/user/arm/toolchain/buildroot-2010.11/output/staging/usr/include
   QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT     = /home/user/arm/toolchain/buildroot-2010.11/output/staging/usr/lib

I got it running now. thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either you provide the Qt libraries in your toolchain or you tell qmake where to find them. Also, I suspect you're calling qmake without the -spec parameters. If you are using the qmake you find in your distribution, it will use the default spec, which is not arm I guess. Add the -spec parameter and point it to the arm mkspec. Also, make sure the generated g++ commands link to the correct Qt libs compiled for arm.

Comment: You'll have to provide the path to the headers and libs for your platform (EGL, OpenGL, X11 etc...) and to the Qt libraries if those are not in your sysroot. You don't specify which config file you're talking about, so no idea. Read the qmake manual and the links provided by liuyi to setup the specification files correctly.

Comment: the links describe how to build Qt itself but I wanna build an example application. I am talking about a file called qconfig.pri located in the mkspecs folder. This file includes a QT_ARCH variable which is set to i386.

Comment: Your question is too generic. What happened after you specified the -spec paramter? Still the same error? In the second link you can find "Create a Target Specific qmake Specification". Also, as I said, read the qmake manual. There you have the specifications of all the qmake variables. You might need to modify some of those according to your environment.

Comment: The qconfig.pri seems to contain information about the build. You should be given that I suppose. It depends on how the libraries where built. You might try simply changing the value of QT_ARCH to arm.

Answer (score -3):

You shall install `QtSDK` for embedded linux befor you use it to build your application. I'm afraid you just have `QtSDK` for x86 right now. After `QtSDK` for embedded linux installed, it has qws/linux-arm-g++ as the default mkspace typically. If you don't have `QtSDK` for embedded linux, you can build it from source. Then run `qmake` to create Makefile for you application.

```
$QTDIR_FOR_ARM/qmake
```

Reference:
[Installing Qt for Embedded Linux](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-embedded-install.html) and [Cross-Compiling Qt for Embedded Linux Applications](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html)

Comment: Ubuntu has the mkspec for arm already. No need to install anything. Also, he already has the libraries compiled for his platform, no need to recompile.